# Why Android Studio shows setupWithNavController not exists?

Tags: android, androidx

`NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController)`

When I run the app, the code is fine, but why it keeps showing compile error like this ?

The bottom navigation I use is in `com.google.android.material:material`, and the bottom navigation in the param is `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView`. I know they are the same thing, but why it complains ?

[image]

Comment: Just restart Android Studio. The lint gets confused sometimes.

Comment: restart works for me. @TheWanderer can you put this as an answer ? I will accept this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just restart Android Studio. The lint gets confused sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue. It's super confusing with all the different android packages now. androidx, android-arch, android-support. All of them in some weird version state with -rcX, alpha-X or beta-X...
Using the following code I got the same error. **But after telling AndroidStudio to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart, it suddenly worked.**

Also I can highly recommend this tutorial: https://proandroiddev.com/android-jetpack-navigationui-a7c9f17c510e

**imports:**

```
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0-alpha07"
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import net.onefivefour.android.ebtimetracker.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(findViewById(R.id.navigation), findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment))
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp()
}
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_graph" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/mainActivity"
    android:name="net.onefivefour.android.ebtimetracker.ui.MainActivity"
    android:label="MainActivity"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/quickEntryFragment"
    android:name="net.onefivefour.android.ebtimetracker.ui.quickentry.QuickEntryFragment"
    android:label="QuickEntryFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_quick_entry" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/templatesFragment"
    android:name="net.onefivefour.android.ebtimetracker.ui.templates.TemplatesFragment"
    android:label="TemplatesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_templates" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/entriesFragment"
    android:name="net.onefivefour.android.ebtimetracker.ui.entries.EntriesFragment"
    android:label="EntriesFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_entries" />

</navigation>
```

Comment: have you added same code for nav_graph.xml and navigation.xml? is there some kind of mistake?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for noticing. I removed of one of them.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with toolbar because i was importing from the old support library instead of new androidx support library. So check your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you correctly applied the three installation steps correctly

1- Add the dependencies to your app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    def nav_version = "2.1.0-alpha02"

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-fragment-ktx
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version" // For Kotlin use navigation-ui-ktx
}
```

2- For Safe args, add the following classpath in your top level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0-alpha02"
    }
}
```

3- You must also apply one of two available plugins.

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs" // or for Kotlin only: apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
```

I had forgotten to apply the navigation safe args in my app build.gradle and it caused me to get this error.

I hope this was helpful to you. :)

Source:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#declaring_dependencies

Comment: Still not working for me after following your steps 

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't have navigation dependencies at your app build.gradle file. Add the lines below and try again.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
```