# setupWithNavController method for toolbar no longer available?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

so previously I had crash with error:

> You must call setGraph() before calling getGraph()

then after reading the solution frem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59290968/you-must-call-setgraph-before-calling-getgraph). it is said that I have to use these lines on my gradle

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0-alpha02"
```

and the error is dissapear. but now I no longer can find `setupWithNavController` method. usually I use this line

```
toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController,appBarConfiguration)
```

but I no longer find that method. what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Android Studio shows setupWithNavController not exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768334/why-android-studio-shows-setupwithnavcontroller-not-exists)

Comment: @murgupluoglu I have tried the solution from there but it just doesn't work, I have tried to restart android studio, clear and rebuild, but I still can't find the method

Comment: That comes from `-ktx` dependencies and you are not adding the `-ktx` dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use any of the [NavigationUI Kotlin extension functions](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/ui/package-summary#extension-functions-summary), you must use the `-ktx` version of the dependencies.

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0-alpha02"
```

Comment: I am using the ktx versions and this is still not working for me.